# Maximising a divisor of an array of values and summing the quotients

Tags: java, optimization, dynamic-programming

Given an array of integer values `P` of length `N`, I am wanting to maximise a value `M` where all values of `P` are floor divided by `M` and summed to a variable `K`, but where `K` is greater than or equal to a value `D`.

The following constraints hold:

- 1 ≤ N ≤ 10,000
- 1 ≤ P[i] ≤ 1,000,000,000
- 1 ≤ D ≤ 10,000,000
- 1 ≤ M ≤ 10,000,000

For example,

```
D = 6, P = [10,11,14,15] and where M starts at 4:
sum([10,11,14,15] / 4) = sum([2,2,3,3]) = 10 # (D <= 10)
sum([10,11,14,15] / 5) = sum([2,2,2,3]) = 9 # (D <= 9)
sum([10,11,14,15] / 6) = sum([1,1,2,2]) = 6 # (D <= 6)
sum([10,11,14,15] / 7) = sum([1,1,2,2]) = 6 * # (D <= 6)
sum([10,11,14,15] / 8) = sum([1,1,1,1]) = 4 # (D > 4) -> break
```

*M is maximised and the sum K is kept above or equal to D.

I've done the following but want to find an approach that is not brute force:

```
long Split(long[] P,int D){


    long K = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    int M = P.length-1;


    while(K >= min_amount) {


        M++;
        K = 0;

        for (long value : P)
            K += value/M;

    }


    return M-1;

}
```

}

Comment: if `M = P.length-1` then why is `M` set to `5` in  your example?  How is `M` initially chosen?

Comment: Using the fact the sum of all elements divided by M will always be greater or equal to the sum of the floored down divisions you could derive an upper bound for M by dividing the sum of all elements by D and then perform a binary search for M between 1 as lower and the calculated number as upper bound. While that probably isn't the perfect solution it'd improve runtime by a lot.

Comment: @MDK Thanks for the response. Could you elaborate on the binary search? Would I be searching for the maximum value of M within the calculated range?

Comment: Since you need to sum up the values it seems that you could use a `LinkedList` and selectively remove values where the divisor is greater since the quotient would be 0 and doesn't affect the sum in this or future iterations.  And for  `value < divisor + divisor` you could just add 1.

Comment: What is the nature of the array?   What happens if you have an array of 1000 values but no value is >= 1000.  If the divisor is based on the array size, then the sum would be zero.

Comment: @WJS I've added the problem constraints to the original post

Comment: I apologize for not fully getting this but consider  `P = [5,7,1,5,2,1,4,5,8,2,3]`  If `M` is `P.length-1` then the sum is 0 and the iterations stop for any positive value `D > 0`.  I don't have the answer but there needs to be an intelligent selection of `M` based possibly on some initial mathematical trait of the array contents and the target `D`

Comment: @Gregory indeed. I previously stated an approach to also find a lower bound, however it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple approach to improve runtime is to use some mathematical properties of your numbers to narrow down the interval in which you search.

Let `S` be the sum over all elements of the array `P`, let `Mmax` be the `M` we are looking for and `Kopt` the `K` calculated with `Mmax`. Then we can state that

`S/Mmax >= Kopt >= D` since the flooring can only reduce K. Therefore `S/D >= Mmax`.

Using this bound you can perform a binary search for the actual `Mmax` between `1` and `S/D`.